# How to get absolute path from FileDialog?

Tags: java, file, awt

I'm creating FileDialog and trying to get a FilePath for FileDialog object.

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD); 
fd.setVisible(true);
String path = ?;
File f = new File(path);
```

In this codes, I need to get a absolute FilePath for using with File object.
How can I get filepath in this situation?

Comment: `fd.getFile();`

Comment: I know that. but it return just file name like "text.txt". I need full-path like "c://text.txt"

Comment: I'm pretty sure it gives you a path relative to the initial directory, which if you don't set, will be the current user's home directory. So just set the intial directory explicitly: `fd.setDirectory("C://");` and treat all paths you get as relative to that.

Comment: Thanks. I tired to "File f = new FIle(fd.getFIle());" and I got Full-path.

Comment: 1) `File f = fd.getFiles()[0];` but check the array is not of 0 length (meaning no file selected) before doing that. 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`File.getAbsolutePath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()):

```java
String path = new File(fd.getFile()).getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: This allways returned a path relative to the program running for me.

Comment: Even when you include the `getAbsolutePath()` call? What OS are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10. What worked for me was the answer below with the `getDirectory` call

Answer (score 23):

You can combine [FileDialog.getDirectory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#getDirectory()) with [FileDialog.getFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#getFile()) to get a full path.

```
String path = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
File f = new File(path);
```

I needed to use the above instead of a call to File.getAbsolutePath() since getAbsolutePath() was returning the path of the current working directory and not the path of the file chosen in the FileDialog.

Comment: It's probably better to use `new File(fd.getDirectory(), fd.getFile())` than trying to concatenate the two components by hand.